# How can I do two foreach loops in php at the same time

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to have $img instead of $filename inside the "a" tag
Where the video directory is

> X/en/videos/action/

and the image directory is

> X/en/videos_images/action/

and the images are named the same as video with a

**.jpg** extension instead.

```
 if($page == "action")
  {
      echo "<div class=\"mainlist\">
      <h1>" . $page . "</h1>";
      foreach(glob("X/en/videos/action/*mp4") as $filename)
      {
          $file = substr($filename,strlen("X/en/videos/action/"));
          echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"300\">";
          echo "<div class='videolist'><a href='?video=$filename'>$img</a></div>";
          echo "</div>";
      }
  }
```

Comment: `$img = str_replace('.mp4', '.jpg', $file)`?

Comment: @u_mulder: Except the paths are different as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the basic appraoch, however you should use `file_exists()` and check that the image actually exists and decide what to do from there.  Just get the `basename()` and build the path with the `.jpg` extension:

```
foreach(glob("X/en/videos/action/*mp4") as $filename)
{
    $img = "X/en/videos_images/action/" . basename($filename, '.mp4') . ".jpg";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"300\">";
    echo "<div class='videolist'><a href='?video=$filename'>$img</a></div>";
}
```

You probably also want to `urlencode($filename)` to use it in a URL.  Plus, you are giving out a lot of information by transferring the entire path in the URL.  Consider just using `basename($filename)` and determining the path in the destination page.

As an alternate since people are proposing `str_replace()`, for those given paths:

```
$img = str_replace(array('videos', '.mp4'), array('videos_images', '.jpg'), $filename);
```

But it's less dynamic if you want to use variable paths.

Comment: Btw, I suppose last `</div>` should be outside `foreach`

Comment: @u_mulder: Sure, wasn't looking at that ;-)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, to have an image, you need to use the img tag.
You can use [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) like this

```
 $img = str_ireplace('.mp4', '.jpg', $filename);
 echo "<div class='videolist'><a href='?video=$filename'><img src='$img'></a></div>";
```

Comment: Except the paths are different as well.

Comment: Oh yep, then i'd probably just use `$img = "X/en/videos_images/action/" .str_ireplace('.mp4', '.jpg', $filename);`

Comment: Then you would have `X/en/videos_images/action/X/en/videos/action/someimage.jpg`